# JQuery AJAX Post Cascading Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to populate dropdowns based on the value of the previous dropdown via AJAX posts, however, the url is not connecting properly with the method in the controller.  Stating the following error in FireBug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:1079/RoundDetail/GetCourses"
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class RoundDetailController : Controller
    {
        private GolfTrackerEntities2 db = new GolfTrackerEntities2();

        public JsonResult GetFacilities(int id)
        {
            var facilities = db.Facilities.Distinct().ToList();
            return Json(facilities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function changeCourses() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $courses = $('#ddlCourses');

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetCourses", "RoundDetail") ",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{ 'facilityId':'" + val + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success:
                    function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                        var list = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                            courseList += '<option value="' + course.Abbr + '">' + course.Name + '</option>';
                        }
                        $courses.html(courseList);

                    }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You should check the reason of the 500, it cannot be caused by the JS.

Comment: what is the best way to do so?

Comment: See server error logs

Comment: As others have mentioned, a 500 error is from your httpd, meaning apache, meaning it's server side code that's blowing up, not client side (javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your controller. You specified another action instead of action causes error, so it is hard to say what problem is. Also please click on row in firebug and take a look at response body - it contains detail information about server error.

Seems for content type `application/json` there is no need to stringify javascript object, and you can pass `{ facilityId: val }` to data.

Also I'm not sure it is correct to build options list using string concatenation - because it is not javascript injection safe. You can use

`$courses.append($("<option ></option>").attr("value", course.Abbr).text(course.Name));`

instead.